# Angular get raw http request before sending

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-httpclient

I am trying to get the HTTP requests before they are send to the server.

My first try was to write a HttpIntercepter like so

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpLoggingInterceptorProvider implements HttpInterceptor
{
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
  {
    console.log('Request To Be Logged:');
    console.dir(req);

    if(req.body)
    {
      try
      {
        let formData = <FormData>req.body;

        if(formData.has('id_front'))
          console.log(formData.get('id_front'));

        if(formData.has('id_back'))
          console.log(formData.get('id_back'));
      }
      catch(err)
      {

      }
    }


    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

This works fine, but is not what i want. I want to get the final composed request as raw text and not as objects.

At the moment the console output [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E28Bk.jpg)

As you can see i don't get any information out of it. I can't see how many or which values are set.

But when i request the body's contents programatically, i can obtain the values like so:

```
let formData = <FormData>req.body;

        if(formData.has('id_front'))
          console.log(formData.get('id_front'));

        if(formData.has('id_back'))
          console.log(formData.get('id_back'));
```

At least i know that something exists in the body except from the type being FormData...

My question

How can i get the raw composed request which will be sent to the server?

Comment: Why don't you just opent the network panel of your browser dev tools? The browser gives that information already, without having any code to write.

Comment: @JBNizet create an answer from it and you get the Vote => It works :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because  the "try" block  is executed after everything else. Angular http request always execute after the rest, so you have to get the data from there or do it in other way

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
```